# .NET App redirects to login page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Im building an application in Visual Studio. When I run the debug mode, It automatically redirects me to the login page. The start page URL is this: http://localhost:52450/Home but That won't load and redirects to http://localhost:52450/Admin/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fHome. The application should be usable even without the login though.

I found this in my web.config file:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">

  <forms loginUrl="/Admin/Login" />

</authentication>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One the of the fixes below will help you.

1. You should enable `Anonymous` authentication method, along with the `Forms` auth.
2. You have added the `Authorize` attribute to your controllers, remove it for now, but add it later when you implement the login page.

Comment: Removing authorize attribute helped, I will accept your answer in a minute!